# Why is the const&& overload of as_const deleted?

Tags: c++, templates, constants, c++17

On a [blog on the progress of C++17](http://talesofcpp.fusionfenix.com/post-23/interlude) I read the following:

> `P0007` proposes a helper function template `as_const`, which simply
>   takes a reference and returns it as a reference to `const`.
>
> ```
> template <typename T> std::add_const_t<T>& as_const(T& t) { return t }
> template <typename T> void as_const(T const&&) = delete;
> ```

Why is the `const&&` overload deleted?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider what would happen if you didn't have that overload, and try to pass in a `const` rvalue:

```
template <typename T> const T &as_const(T &t) { return t; }
struct S { };
const S f() { return S{}; }
int main() {
  // auto & ref = as_const(S()); // correctly detected as invalid already
  auto & ref = as_const(f()); // accepted
}
```

This would be accepted because `T` would be deduced as `const S`, and temporaries can bind to `const S &`. The result would be that you accidentally get an lvalue reference to a temporary, which will be destroyed right after `ref` has been initialised. Almost all users taking lvalues (whether variables or function parameters) don't expect to be passed temporaries; silently accepting temporaries means that you easily silently get dangling references.

Comment: @dyp Yes, exactly, otherwise it wouldn't be a problem. :) Perhaps I should expand a bit on that. Thanks T.C. for the edit by the way, I initially had an example with an xvalue but forgot to update the text when I simplified the example.

Comment: Yes my comment was meant more as some further explanation of your answer. I'm not sure though if this restriction is useful; `as_const(T const&&)` could simply return a `T const&&`, and the compiler warn about binding a `T const&` variable to a `T const&&` in a variable definition does not extend lifetime.

Comment: @dyp Then there could simply be an `as_const(T &&)` (no `const` in there) which returns `T const &&` overload. Yes, that would be possible, but I suspect that calling `as_const` and passing in an rvalue is more likely to be a mistake than something that needs to be supported.

Comment: In motivation, there are example about ADL between `void foo(const T&)` and `bool foo(T&)`, so the deleted version don't allow to choose between `void foo(const T&&)` and `bool foo(T&&)`...

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't understand your comment. As I understand it, if you have a `T &t`, you can call `foo(t)` (your second overload), or `foo(const_cast<const T &>(t))` (your first overload). The motivation section covers the basic use of `as_const`: make it possible to write `foo(as_const(t))` to get the first overload. It's not related to the deleted overload of `as_const`.

Comment: @hvd: I mean that `foo(temp())` vs `foo(as_const(temp()))`, you cannot use the second one.

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah, yeah, that's what I meant is more likely a mistake than something that needs to be supported. :) I can't think of a valid use case for having separate `foo(T &&)` and `foo(const T &&)` overloads, or separate `foo(T &&)` and `foo(const T &)` overloads, where you would ever want to call the `const` version with `temp()` as the argument. Am I overlooking some obvious use case that you do see?

Comment: I don't see neither, but it not for that there are no cases