# Why does as_const forbid rvalue arguments?

Tags: c++, rvalue, c++17

I wanted to ask why `as_const` forbids rvalue arguments, [according to](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) cppreference.com (i.e. why the Standards folks made it so, not why cppreference.com specifically quoted them on that. And also not where in the spec the intent of the committee is codified, just for making sure :))). This (artificial) example would yield an error (user wants to make it const to keep COW quiet)

```
QChar c = as_const(getQString())[0];
```

[Another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34566125/1848654) notes that if we *just* remove the deletion of the rvalue reference overload, it would silently transform rvalues to lvalues. Right, but why not handle rvalues gracefully and return const rvalues for rvalue input and const lvalues for lvalue input?

Comment: thanks, yes it's a dupe. closing ASAP

Comment: ah, i'm not satisfied with the answer given there.. reopening! Please find my notes attached to the question

Comment: Why not have it like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9453435/34509 .. I didn't see any immediate danger back then either.

Comment: @Mehrdad i'm of the opinion that the above QChar example is a usecase. It prevents calling non-const member functions on rvalues. For COW-classes, even having a ref qualifier is not enough to prevent COW-ing, I think. The only safe way is having a const overload. And `as_const` comes right into the place to support that. Even if there seems no use case, what danger is there to support it? If there's a real danger, why not also forbid `static_cast<const Foo&&>(getFoo())` then?

Comment: (Sorry, deleted my comment since I basically put it into an answer.) But what I meant is this: why would you prevent calling a non-const method on an rvalue? Like, what error would it be trying to prevent? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Mehrdad a performance penalty due to copy on write (COW) in a non-const method overload.

Comment: Interesting use case, but I think it's an implicit assumption that if a method has both a const and a non-const version, then they should both behave (reasonably) identically. The premise of COW is that you copy on *writes*, and calling a non-const version of a method whose const version is also available semantically *shouldn't* result in a write (because the const version logically wouldn't). So if that's how you're implementing COW, then your implementation is arguably wrong. Right?

Comment: One deeper reason could be that they want to discourage "magic calls". Even if it is legit under the hood, it can be misleading at first. It's like, having to think about both non-const and const implementation if you assume them to be different.

Comment: @Mehrdad that's how it's done usually, though. COW doesn't need to perfectly detect when writes are done, it only needs to overapproximate it. It's cheap to detect it in the non-const overload. If the overloads return a naked pointer or a reference for instance, that's the only place for checking it. Otherwise you need to return a proxy object with `op=` overloaded.. which in all humbleness is quite an overkill :)

Comment: Anyway, it was just an example. My gut feeling says that the language should grade power before safety. I'm a bit disappointed that in this case, they chose safety-first

Comment: `as_const_ref` could be added where it's allowed also for rvalues IMHO. The `ref` at the end would make it clear that it introduces an indirection.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: If that's how it's usually done, I'd argue it's usually done wrong, and this is the overapproximation penalty for doing it wrong. =P But if you think about it, this is pretty consistent with what the language already does -- what you're asking for is basically like asking why doesn't C++ allow binding rvalues to lvalue references? It's power vs. safety there too, and they chose safety. Similar here. I'm not sure `as_const_ref` would be used frequently enough to justify it, so that's probably why they didn't do it. How often do people do COW (esp. an approximate one)?(!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One reason might be that it could be dangerous on rvalues due to lack of ownership transfer

```
for (auto const &&value : as_const(getQString()))  // whoops!
{
}
```

and that there might not be a compelling use case to justify disregarding this possibility.

Comment: Hm, that seems a compelling example of danger introduced! Thanks. Having it work for rvalues would be so useful, but I can understand that they don't want people to walk into this trap. Now I see that `std::cref` is also deleted for rvalue arguments, perhaps symmetry with it was another argument?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Well, sure, but that's probably getting the cause and effect backwards... I imagine that was also probably due to the same reason.

Comment: "lack of ownership transfer", what does that mean? I guess `QString` is COW implementation with brittle semantics where non-`const` item access induces preventive copying and `const` access does not but returns reference (that's very unsafe, sloppy design, but I'm assuming it). I still can't see what this example is about. I can imagine storing a pointer to whatever `value` refers to, a temporary or an item in the string's buffer, and that that pointer becomes dangling pretty fast. But that's nothing to do with `as_const`. Or is it?

Comment: Oh, the rvalue reference to `const` is bound to reference, so the temporary string's lifetime is not extended. I was misled by the "lack of ownership transfer" comment. What does that mean?

Answer (score 8):

The problem is to handle lifetime extension

```
const auto& s = as_const(getQString()); // Create dangling pointer
QChar c = s[0]; // UB :-/
```

A possibility would be the following overload (instead of the deleted one)

```
template< typename T >
const T as_const(T&& t) noexcept(noexcept(T(std::forward<T>(t))))
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

which involves extra construction, and maybe other pitfalls.

Comment: Johannes' suggestion of `as_const_ref` would deal with this, wouldn't it? Then one wouldn't expect a lifetime extension.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: As my concern is lifetime extension, indeed, if we stay with cases without life time extension requirement, `as_const_ref` seems good.

Comment: I think your alternative should say `std::move(t)`?

Comment: @user541686: `std::forward<T>(t)` used.

Comment: Ooh, good call. I didn't notice `t` might be an lvalue reference here!

Answer (score 1):

*(I accidentally answered the wrong question [to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65716682/4573247) of this Q&A, after mis-reading it; I'm moving my answer to this question instead, the question which my answer actually addressed)*

[P0007R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0007r1.html) introduced `std::as_const` as part of C++17. The accepted proposal did not mention rvalues at all, but the previous revision of it, [P0007R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0007r0.html), contained a closing discussion on rvalues [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### IX. Further Discussion
>
> The above implementation only supports safely re-casting an l-value as
> const (even if it may have already been const). It is probably
> desirable to have xvalues and prvalues also be usable with as_const,
> but there are some issues to consider.
>
> [...]
>
> An alternative implementation which would support all of the forms
> used above, would be:
>
> ```
> template< typename T >
> inline const T &
> as_const( const T& t ) noexcept
> {
>     return t;
> }
>
> template< typename T >
> inline const T
> as_const( T &&t ) noexcept( noexcept( T( t ) ) )
> {
>     return t;
> }
> ```
>
> We believe that such an implementation helps to deal with lifetime
> extension issues for temporaries which are captured by as_const, but
> we have not fully examined all of the implications of these forms. We
> are open to expanding the scope of this proposal, **but we feel that
> the utility of a simple-to-use as_const is sufficient even without the
> expanded semantics.**

So `std::as_const` was basically added only for lvalues as the implications of implementing it for rvalues were not fully examined by the original proposal, even if the return by value overload for rvalue arguments was at least visited. The final proposal, on the other hand, focused on getting the utility in for the common use case of lvalues.

[P2012R0](http://www7.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2020/p2012r0.pdf) aims to address the hidden dangers of range-based for loops

> #### Fix the range‐based for loop, Rev0
>
> The range-based for loop became the most important control structure
> of modern C++. It is the loop to deal with all elements of a
> container/collection/range.
>
> However, due to the way it is currently defined, it can easily
> introduce lifetime problems in non-trivial but simple applications
> implemented by ordinary application programmers.
>
> [...]
>
> **The symptom**
>
> Consider the following code examples when iterating over elements of
> an element of a collection:
>
> ```
> std::vector<std::string> createStrings(); // forward declaration
> …
> for (std::string s : createStrings()) … // OK
> for (char c : createStrings().at(0)) … // UB (fatal runtime error)
> ```
>
> While iterating over a temporary return value works fine, **iterating
> over a reference to a temporary return value is undefined behavior.**
>
> [...]
>
> **The Root Cause for the problem**
>
> The reason for the undefined behavior above is that according to the
> current specification, the range-base for loop internally is expanded
> to multiple statements: [...]
>
> And the following call of the loop:
>
> ```
> for (int i : createOptInts().value()) … // UB (fatal runtime error)
> ```
>
> is defined as equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> auto&& rg = createOptInts().value(); // doesn’t extend lifetime of returned optional
> auto pos = rg.begin();
> auto end = rg.end();
> for ( ; pos != end; ++pos ) {
>  int i = *pos;
>  …
>  }
> ```
>
> By rule, all temporary values created during the initialization of the
> reference `rg` that are not directly bound to it are destroyed before
> the raw for loop starts.
>
> [...]
>
> **Severity of the problem**
>
> [...]
>
> As another example for restrictions caused by this problem consider
> using `std::as_const()` in a range-based for loop:
>
> std::vector vec; for (auto&& val : std::as_const(getVector())) {
> … }
>
> Both `std::ranges` with `operator |` and `std::as_const()` **have a
> deleted overload for rvalues to disable this and similar uses.** With
> the proposed fix things like that could be possible. We can definitely
> discuss the usability of such examples, **but it seems that there are
> more example than we thought where the problem causes to `=delete`
> function calls for rvalues.**

These gotchas is one argument to avoid allowing an `std::as_const()` overload for rvalues, but if P2012R0 gets accepted, such an overload could arguably be added (if someone makes a proposal and shows a valid use case for it).

Answer (score -2):

Because as_const doesn't take the argument as const reference.
Non-const lvalue references can't bind to temporaries.

The forwarding reference overload is explicitly deleted.